# Convergence, continuity, differentiability of an improper integral

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Find the areas of uniform convergence, continuity, differentiability of the integral

> $$I(\alpha )=\int_{0 }^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{1+x^{2}}dx$$

I do not know how to apply the Cauchy or Weierstrass criterion here. Are they actually needed in this case? And also having no ideas how to investigate the continuity and  differentiability

Comment: Lebesgue, Riemann?

Comment: @copper.hat I need to find the areas of uniform convergence

Comment: What do you mean by uniform convergence?

Comment: @copper.hat Uniform convergence is a type of convergence of a sequence of real valued functions $$ \{f_n:X\to \mathbb{R}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}{f n
​ 
 :X→R} $$
n=1
∞
​ 
  requiring that the difference to the limit function $$ f:X\to \mathbb{R}f:X→R$$ can be estimated uniformly on X, that is, independently of x∈X.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the various forms of convergence, but I do not understand what uniform means in the above. Uniform with respect to what?

Comment: @copper.hat respect to the integral? I need to investigate  for which  alpha  does the integral converges uniformly. Could you help me please?

Comment: I would, but I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I believe in this case, it would refer to the uniformity with respect to $\alpha$ of $\int_0^N\dfrac{\cos \alpha x}{1+x^2}\,dx {\to} I(\alpha)$ as $N \to \infty$.